# React Native: How to create a menu brought up from bottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to recreate the following, where a menu is brought up from bottom when a button is pressed, but lost as to where to start. How can I go about doing so?

Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is the best so far. Works on Android and iOS.

https://github.com/prscX/react-native-bottom-action-sheet

[image]

Note: it requires native modules so it won't work on Expo.

Alternatively, you use this component from NativeBase:
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#actionsheet-def-headref

[image]
[image]

FYI: I haven't tested `react-native-bottom-action-sheet`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module like [this](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-action-sheet) for an example. IMO this can be done in two ways:

1. Slide a `View` with animation like in the library linked above.
2. Use a `Modal` component that will slide from the bottom (it's actually a default behaviour of this component). Remember to add a margin on top of the content to don't slide it to the top of the screen).

Comment: Sorry but do you mind showing a sample of each? Trying to wrap my head around it but can't seem to grasp it too well.

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.